# Is there a way to set the size of Resharper's DataTips?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I am using Visual Studio 2022 (latest update) with Resharper Ultimate (also the latest version).
Here's what my window looks like during my latest debugging session:

[image]

The Resharper DataTips completely obscure my code.  And each other

So I went into *Tools >> Options >> Environment >> Fonts and Colors*

I changed the category to "Text Editor" and scrolled down to "Reshaper Debugger Tips".  Changed the font size there.  No effect whatsoever.  Not even when I shut down and restarted visual Studio.

Does anyone know how to shrink these down?  I do know how to remove them completely but that's not what I want.  I just want them to stop obscuring everything.

(I know these tips are from Resharper because when I disable it, they disappear.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be down to whether you are using the Visual Studio IntelliSense Font or the Text Editor Font for the debug hints (`ReSharper`->`Options...`->`Tools`->`Debugger`->`Editor Integration`):

[image]

Try setting it to the 'Text Editor font'. Not sure exactly which Font setting (under `Tools`->`Options...`->`Fonts and Colors`) defines the IntelliSense font though, but you could scroll through the 'Show settings for' list to see if any are set larger than they need to be. Or you could reset all your Visual Studio font settings. Some of the font settings may only take effect when restarting Visual Studio though.

Note (relating to your comments), this could also be due to using small fonts and high zoom levels.

Comment: I totally want to mark this as the answer.  But it simply does not work.  Not only does it not work, it has no effect on the size of the tooltips.  I will admit that seems bizarre to me;.  That's exactly the sort of setting I was looking for.  I did not realize that setting existed.  But strangely, it changes nothing.

Comment: On further investigation I think this is a combination of two effects:  First you have whatever font size you've set the text editor to.  But the second setting is the editor zoom level.  I personally use standard Windows method to zoom a display in or out:   CTRL + MOUSEWHEEL.   I use that throughout all Windows applications.  And I had basically set a small font size in VS but used a high zoom level.  Once I cranked up the font size and then didn't need to zoom in as much, the Resharper DataTips started to match up much better

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Perhaps you need a bigger monitor or glasses ;) All that zooming and scaling can look a little weird sometimes. I have added a note to my answer to reflect your comments.